Numerical methods derivation

a)
Derive a method in the form of $y_{n+1}=\alpha_{0}y_{n-1}+\alpha_{1}y_{n}+h\beta f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ for the numerical solution of the initial value problem $y'=f(t,y), y(0)=y_{0}$, where $a_{0}\neq 0$ and $\beta \neq 0$(This means you need to find the values of $a_{0}$,$a_{1}$ and $\beta$.


b) Determine the order of the derived method


c) Is the derived method weakly stable or relatively stable?

First of all, although I solved some questions related to numerical methods it is the first time I am seeing a question like "derive a method". That is too confusing for me because I think I can obtain infinitely many methods and I have no restriction.
But once I derive stability means that all the roots of the polynomial $p(r)=r^{2}-a_{1}r-a_{0}$ are inside the disk $|z|\leq 1$ and if all the roots with modulus 1 are simple the method is stable.
Strong and weak stability is related to whether the roots exactly satisfy $|z|<1$ lie in this disk. Order of the derived method is related to local truncation error if it is $O(h^{p+1})$ the order should be $p$.
But my main concern is derivation of this method and I also do not have too much practice about this subject I only know the things in theory therefore I may also need help about how to find order of the method in the next steps. Also I would like to ask about relative stability. I am maths graduate just completed masters and want to study numerical mathematics as my main subject.

What an utterly stupid problem (not your fault). At no point in your life will this exercise help you think appropriatly about any numerical method. Your intuition is correct, there's an infinitude of answers, most with (b) zero (c) neither. But that's not the point. Ask yourself: What is the purpose of computation? I posit: Insight. Does the exercise discuss any problem for which insight can be gained? No. So what's the meaning of discussing stability and order concepts? None.
Stick to it though. The subject is both elegant and surprising. Sadly, books and lectures seldomly do it justice.

In one-step or Runge-Kutta methods you would explore their properties by inserting abstract Taylor series. This includes computing compositions of power series with symbolic variables as coefficients, so it gets messy fast.
For multi-step methods as in the present case it is largely sufficient to explore their behavior for the class of test equations $y'=\lambda y$, with $\lambda$ any complex number. This fixes the coefficients of the method if you demand maximal error order.
The stability condition you describe is for zero-stability, that is, that the most trivial test equation $y'=0$ gets solved correctly and without error growth if the initial values get some small noise added.
General stability is concerned with whether these roots stay inside the unit disks also for $\lambda \ne 0$, $Re(\lambda)\le0$ in the test equation. More general stability ideas try to grasp the behavior for non-linear DE.
Thus to start reduce the application of the test equation to the equation
$$
e^h=\alpha_0e^{-h}+\alpha_1+h\beta e^h+O(h^{p+1}),
$$
replace the exponentials by their power series and compare coefficients.
What you get should be related to the backward differentiation formula of order 2.

How can we solve $a_{0}$, $a_{1}$ and $\beta$

By solving the system of linear equations you get when comparing or collecting coefficients of terms of equal degree in $h$.
